# Error Converting Data type nvarcar to float

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the query I am trying to run...

```
 SELECT *,STUFF(PartNumber,1,3,'')
 FROM [devbivarcom].[Products].[Products]
 ORDER BY CAST(STUFF(PartNumber,1,3,'')AS FLOAT)
```

Any ideas on why I might be receiving the error?

Thanks

Comment: what do you have in your field `PartNumber`. If some sample data so people can understand.

Comment: Any special characters in your data, like dollar signs?  Or is it 100% strictly numbers/decimal points?

Answer (score 3):

You are receiving an error because the characters you are converting are not a floating point number.  You can do:

```
SELECT *, STUFF(PartNumber,1,3,'')
FROM [devbivarcom].[Products].[Products]
ORDER BY (case when isnumeric(STUFF(PartNumber,1,3,'')) = 1
               then CAST(STUFF(PartNumber,1,3,'')AS FLOAT)
          end);
```

If you want to find the offending values, do:

```
SELECT *, STUFF(PartNumber,1,3,'')
FROM [devbivarcom].[Products].[Products]
WHERE isnumeric(STUFF(PartNumber,1,3,'')) = 0 and PartNumber is not null;
```

EDIT:

`isnumeric()` is known to have some problems in identifying values.  For instance, it identifies `'.'` as valid when that string doesn't convert correctly.  For most purposes, it is sufficient. You can enhance it with other conditions, such as:

```
AND (<col> <> '.')
```

Comment: Of course `ISNUMERIC()=0` won't identify all values that can't be converted to `FLOAT` (e.g. `$`).