# Select Statement Order by Decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server

I ran this query....

```
SELECT *, STUFF(PartNumber,1,3,'')
FROM [devbivarcom].[Products].[Products]
ORDER BY (case when isnumeric(STUFF(PartNumber,1,3,'')) = 1
               then CAST(STUFF(PartNumber,1,3,'')AS FLOAT)
          end);
```

to change

```
LA-1.3
LC-4.12
LC-4.25
LC-4.5
LC-4.975
LC-40.0
LC-48.0
LC-5.0
LC-5.5
LC-5.75
```

into

```
LA-1.3
LC-4.12
LC-4.25
LC-4.5
LC-4.975
LC-5.0
LC-5.5
LC-5.75
LC-40.0
LC-48.0
```

I was wondering how to order by A-Z as well as order by decimal.  I thought the query I ran would do the trick but it doesn't.

I would really appreciate the help and thank you.

Comment: What do you mean?, how would you want to order your results?

Comment: The query doesn't order them after a decimal so i get ABC60.0 and then after that ill get ABC7.0

Comment: You already [asked this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21581831/error-converting-data-type-nvarcar-to-float)

Answer (score 1):

Any good coder creates a simple test database.

Here is mine in [tempdb] with your data in table [products]

```
-- Just playing
use tempdb;
go

-- Create table
create table products
(
pid int identity(1,1) primary key,
psort varchar(16)
);
go

-- Add data
insert into products (psort)
values
('LA-1.3'),
('LC-4.12'),
('LC-4.25'),
('LC-4.5'),
('LC-4.975'),
('LC-40.0'),
('LC-48.0'),
('LC-5.0'),
('LC-5.5'),
('LC-5.75');
go

insert into products (psort) values (NULL);
insert into products (psort) values ('');

-- Show the data
select * from products;
go
```

[image]

You will notice that I did add bad data to the table, NULL and EMPTY string to do negative testing.

If I was guaranteed that the string was always >= 4 characters and the last section of the string was a number, it would be a snap.

Since life is hardly perfect, we need to code for those cases.

```
-- Order data
select 
  * 
from 
  products
order by 
  case 
      when len(psort) < 3 then ''
      else substring(psort,1,3)
  end,
  case 
      when len(psort) < 4 then ''
      when isnumeric(substring(psort,4,len(psort) - 4)) = 1 then
      cast(substring(psort,4,len(psort) - 4) as float)
      else ''
  end
go
```

[image]

The ISNUMERIC function as written by Microsoft has a little known bug.  It tells you that a . is a valid number.

This case will probably blow up the code.  Either test for that case or download a couple inline table functions I created to handle it.

Please see article "Is my string a number!"

http://craftydba.com/?p=6987

Comment: Thanks again!  I get an error converting data type nvarchar to float :(

Comment: also when i change as float to as nvarchar it still doesn't sort my partnumbers correctly.. SMFLP2F-7.0
SMFLP2F-9.9
SMFLP3.0
SMFLP3.5
SMFLP3.8
SMFLP36.0
SMFLP4.0
SMFLP4.25

Comment: @user3241586 Of course not!  If you cast (<blah> as nvarchar()) it will sort by Alpha Characters, the same output that you did not want!

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using?  From the MSDN conversion chart at bottom, there should be no issue.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx  Are there double decimals in the data.  If so, that is another issue!  Change the code to REPLACE() periods with a empty string ''.  BTW- had no issue with nvarchar() cast with  2014 CTP 2

Comment: cast(replace(substring(psort,4,len(psort) - 4), '.', '') as float) - The only thing that will break this is if you max out the range of a floating point number.  You could always use bigint, but again, depends on your data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select partnumber, 
    substring(partnumber,1, charindex('-',partnumber)-1),
    convert(decimal(20,4),substring(partnumber,charindex('-',partnumber)+1,100))
from products
order by 2,3
```

The **100** in the 3rd line is really a lazy way... you can do len(str) - charindex(str)... if you'd prefer.